# Puppeteer: page.evaluate() returns empty object instead ISO date string

Tags: javascript, date, puppeteer

According to the [Puppeteer docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.0.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args), `page.evaluate()` returns a non-serializable value. They link to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description), where it's explained what `JSON.stringify()` converts or not.

I'm trying to get `Date` values (as ISO strings), but empty object are returned. The MDN docs says the following about `Date` objects:

> The instances of `Date` implement the `toJSON()` function by returning a string (the same as `date.toISOString()`). Thus, they are treated as strings.

Here an example to reproduce it:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); // v5.0.0

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({devtools: true});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('about:blank');

    let date = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return new Date();
    });

    // Expected an ISO date string but empty object returned 
    console.log(date); // Output: {}

    await browser.close();
})();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: This does seem a bit confusing. See the open issue: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new Date() creates a new date object. If you want ISO date string use following,

```js
new Date().toISOString()
```